# IncrediBuild - Error: First character of string should be '0' or '1'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Update: This issue is in a C++ (non-cli) project.  Unfortunately, there is no error info other than what was presented to me via the IDE. I was required to upgrade my IDE from VS2017 to VS2019; when importing a project from VS2017 everything was fine until I tried to do a build. I received the following error/build failure from IncrediBuild:

```
   Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.6.0.
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
   1>------ Build started: Project: XXXXX, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
   1>First character of string should be '0' or '1'.
   1>Error: First character of string should be '0' or '1'.
   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've never encountered a build error like this and have searched for an answer and not found one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, that little amount of info is not enough to reproduce anything, let alone is it a [mcve]. Please also consider filing a bug report.

Comment: No idea but I have never found upgrading projects from one version of visual studio to another to be very successful, and I never had to deal with incredibuild. I would recreate your project from scratch.

Comment: Can use use the `VS 2017` tool set version `141` from within `VS 2019` and see if it allows you to build?

Comment: Also, is this `C++` or `C++/CLI`?

Comment: @WBuck I will try that as it didn't occur to me.  And its a C++ non-CLI.

Comment: @John 1 I've heard that, but the project went from VS 2015 to VS 2017 without issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can also be fixed by forcing IncrediBuild to use MSBuild.  You can do this by adding a registry key in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Xoreax\IncrediBuild\Builder` called `UseMSBuild` and setting it to 1.

Comment: Will the project still be "accelerated" ? I'm interested by the caching feature of incredibuild

Answer (score 1):

Likewise. You can upgrade to incredibuild9_45.

Comment: That could be a comment?